# Community promotion ads page not found 404

Tags: support

There are only about five (5) ads available. Namely, Carlisle and cricket, Carlisle and Undocumented features, Cereda and the duck, Beaton's lowercase, and Hupfer's Arabic numerals.

What happened with the rest? thanks.

[image]

Comment: do you have any adblock plus or ghostery installed? Can you try without them?

Comment: Just checked and I get the same (only five images showing in the list).

Comment: Thought it might help to have a link: http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/ads/display/6473 Only the ads for chat are showing. I haven't changed any browser settings since I last saw it working. (Would an adblock etc affect the stats page?)

Comment: Seems to be fixed now.

Comment: @percusse lol no sir, I don't.

Comment: @NicolaTalbot thanks for checking.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the problem can no longer be reproduced.

Comment: @Werner I understand the voting part, and you're welcome to vote - we've had enough of those votes - to close it, so it satisfies the status quo of the community at large, but being off-topic, is somewhat a stretch that only satisfies a closed mindset. Did I altered, or modified the above jpeg with one of your favorite image manipulation programs? But either way... I'm fine with it

Comment: @doed: My vote-to-close options are: (1) duplicate; it's not, (2) unclear; it's not, (3) too broad; it's not, (4) primarily opinion-based; it's not. That leaves me with (5) off-topic. Under off-topic, I chose "other", which suggests, by default, the introductory reason as "I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because...". Sure, it's not off-topic, but one is limited in the reasons one can choose. I should have removed the "off-topic" reference in the comment, but the question will still be closed under the "off-topic" banner as there are no other viable options.

Comment: @Werner Even though the problem is now fixed, it would be interesting to know what caused the glitch. I'm sure we've had questions before on meta about a non-functioning part of the site that have been answered with a confirmation that it's now working rather than simply being closed.